# Modal routes in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried to implement Modal router as in the [react router example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/modal-gallery) but It works when used with `Link` but it doesn't work when I try to use `history.push`. I am trying to implement multilevel modal with programmatically navigating through. Check the [stack-blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-routable-modal-lyg9w5?file=src/index.js)

```js
// This works
<Link
  to={{
      pathname: `/img/${id}`,
      state: { background: location }
   }}
 >
   <Thumbnail color={color} />
   <p>{title}</p>
</Link>

// This doesn't
<a href="#" onClick={
  () => history.push({
      pathname: `/img/${id}`,
      state: { background: location }
  })
}>
    <Thumbnail color={color} />
    <p>{title}</p>
</div>

// My Router
<div>
  <Switch location={background || location}>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/contacts" exact component={Contacts} />
  </Switch>

  {background && <Route path="/contact/:name" children={<Modal />} />}
</div>
```

How do I fix this to work without `Link` tag? What is the error in the code used?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be solved by adding event.preventDefault().
Because when you click on the link, whole page is reloaded and history.push() is never executed

```
<a href="#" onClick={
  (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault()
    history.push({
      pathname: `/img/${id}`,
      state: { background: location }
  }})
}>
```